# Silverlight: How to display items in a grid?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm using Silverlight 4. I know how to display items in a vertical or horizontal list using a `ListControl` or `ItemsControl`. However, I want to display items in a grid, like you'd see Windows Explorer viewing in grid of icons. How can I do this? Is there a control, or must I use a hack like ItemControls of ItemControls?

Comment: You want to add wrapping to the `ItemsControl`. Not sure how you'd do that though. Can you update your question to make it clear you want automatic filling from an `ItemsSource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want the wrappanel in the silverlight toolkit.  here's an old example but you get the idea: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/11/05/silverlight-toolkit-wrappanel.aspx